# Share first level cache between different sessions?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, session, caching

Is it possible for different NHibernate sessions to share one 1st level cache? I`ve tried to implement it using interceptors and listeners. All works fine except Session.Evict().

```
public class SharedCache :
    EmptyInterceptor,
    IFlushEntityEventListener,
    ILoadEventListener,
    IEvictEventListener,
    ISharedCache {
    [ThreadStatic]
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<object, object>> cache;

    private ISessionFactory factory;

    public SharedCache() {
        this.cache = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<object, object>>();
    }

    public override object Instantiate(string clazz, EntityMode entityMode, object id) {
        var entityCache = this.GetCache(clazz);
        if (entityCache.ContainsKey(id))
            return entityCache[id];

        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(clazz));
        this.factory.GetClassMetadata(clazz).SetIdentifier(entity, id, entityMode);
        return entity;
    }

    private Dictionary<object, object> GetCache(string clazz) {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(clazz))
            cache.Add(clazz, new Dictionary<object, object>());

        return cache[clazz];
    }

    public void Configure(Configuration config) {
        config.SetInterceptor(this);
        config.SetListener(ListenerType.FlushEntity, this);
        config.SetListener(ListenerType.Load, this);
        config.SetListener(ListenerType.Evict, this);
    }

    public void Initialize(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.factory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent ev) {
        var entry = ev.EntityEntry;

        var entityCache = this.GetCache(ev.EntityEntry.EntityName);

        if (entry.Status == Status.Deleted) {
            entityCache.Remove(entry.Id);
            return;
        }

        if (!entry.ExistsInDatabase && !entityCache.ContainsKey(entry.Id))
            entityCache.Add(entry.Id, ev.Entity);
    }


    public void OnLoad(LoadEvent ev, LoadType loadType) {
        var entityCache = this.GetCache(ev.EntityClassName);

        if (entityCache.ContainsKey(ev.EntityId))
            ev.Result = entityCache[ev.EntityId];
    }

    public void OnEvict(EvictEvent ev) {
        var entityName = ev.Session.GetEntityName(ev.Entity);
        var entityCache = this.GetCache(entityName);
        var id = ev.Session.GetIdentifier(ev.Entity);

        entityCache.Remove(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: why                              ?

Comment: Generally bacause of nhibernate sessions are not thread safe. So one should open session in each thread. But also first level cache is required. So I decided to create my own first level cache across sessions.

Comment: If you need a cross-session cache, why don't you use the 2nd-level cache?

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea... the session cache is not just a cache, the session is an isolated unit of work.

Comment: 2nd-level cache disassembles entities, thats why I don't use it. I need one unit of work for all threads.

Comment: again, why? why does it bother you that it disassembles entities? it does so for good reasons: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/24/NHibernate-and-the-second-level-cache-tips.aspx You would be basically subverting Hibernate's careful design by sharing 1st level cache.

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer, thanks for your reply. I took your advice and decided not to share 1st level cache. Instead I open session in each thread and then merge entities to primary session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No 1rst level or session cache cannot be shared if you want to share a cache you should use the 2nd level cache which goes with the session factory - [see the docs](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/performance.html#performance-cache)

you have to be careful as the cache will not be invalidated if the data is changed outside of nhibernate sessions eg via triggers or some other client - or another instance of your code running on another machine